# Oracle LISTAGG case return distinct values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, listagg

I am writing a ORACLE select statement with LISTAGG. It works but when I was validating the data, I saw duplicates like 1:1,1:1,2:2,2:2.

I verified that the database do have duplicate. The query is for two tables in a one to many relationship. Below is a snippet of my query but I changed the column names etc..

how can I modified the following query to return unique values for each person?

Thanks

```
SELECT Table1.PERSON_ID, 
       Table1.FIRST_NAME,
       Table1.MIDDLE_NAME,
       Table1.LAST_NAME,

LISTAGG(case  
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '1' then '1:1'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '2' then '2:2'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '3' then '3:3'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '4' then '4:4'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '5' then '5:5'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '6' then '6:6'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '7' then '7:7'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '8' then '8:8'
        when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '9' then '9:9'


      else ''

 end, ',')  
WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Table2.DESCRIPTION )  

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2

ON Table2.PERSON_ID = Table1.PERSON_ID
GROUP BY Table1.PERSON_ID,Table1.FIRST_NAME,Table1.MIDDLE_NAME, Table1.LAST_NAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Table2` has `PERSON_ID` as foreign key pointing to `Table1`, what you need to do is to replace

```
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table2.PERSON_ID = Table1.PERSON_ID
```

with

```
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT PERSON_ID, DESCRIPTION FROM Table2) T2
ON T2.PERSON_ID = Table1.PERSON_ID
```

and then change `Table2` to `T2` in `LISTAGG()` (including in the `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)` clause!)

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, you need to do the `DISTINCT` in a subquery:

```
SELECT PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME,
        LISTAGG(val, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DESCRIPTION )
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Table1.PERSON_ID, Table1.FIRST_NAME, Table1.MIDDLE_NAME, Table1.LAST_NAME, Table2.Description
             (case when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '1' then '1:1'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '2' then '2:2'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '3' then '3:3'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '4' then '4:4'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '5' then '5:5'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '6' then '6:6'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '7' then '7:7'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '8' then '8:8'
                   when Table2.DESCRIPTION = '9' then '9:9'
                   else ''
              end) as val
      FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN
           Table2
           ON Table2.PERSON_ID = Table1.PERSON_ID
     ) 
GROUP BY PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, LAST_NAME;
```

Comment: I correct my query as your specified. I am getting the following error: ORA-00904: "DBName"."VIEW"."DESCRIPTION": invalid identifier. In the posted query, DBNAME.VIEW is 'Table2'. Trying to figure out how to fix this.

Comment: In Oracle you can't refer to a table name when it is nested more than one level within the outer query. Here Table2 appears in the innermost subquery (the join), it does not appear in the middle subquery, and it is used in the outer query. To save it, the middle query should be given a name, and that name be used in the outer query. Or just say `DESCRIPTION` in `ORDER BY`. BUT: This solution doesn't make much sense. `SELECT DISTINCT` should be done on `Table2` before the join, not on the result of the join. Just fix it as suggested and compare EXECUTE PLAN for the two solutions offered.

Comment: @John . . . The inner query simply needs to return `DESCRIPTION`.